# Temporary Load Bearing wall support

Tags: load-bearing

Whats the best way to support an 18'-6" span of load bearing wall, so a LAM Beam can be installed?

Comment: Much more info needed and some pictures or drawings illustrating what the load bearing wall is supporting and upon what is it bearing.

Comment: Start by reading this tutorial https://www.familyhandyman.com/walls/how-to-install-a-loadbearing-beam/

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'd need a lot more info before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.